# Выборка доступных значений по параметру

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос MySQL (хотя, думаю, одним запросом здесь не обойдется).

Суть - возможность выставления пользователем своего отношения к другому пользователю (как ВКонтакте - выбор второй половинки, братьев, сестер и т. д.).

Есть две таблицы:

`relations_types`

- `id`
- `title`
- `sex` - важность пола второго пользователя (например, для позиции "второй половинки" или брата (странно, если брат будет женского пола:)) принимает значения: 0 - все равно, 1 - мужской, 2 - женский, 3 - зависит от пола самого пользователя (т. е. если женский, то параметр становится мужского пола, и наоборот)
- `is_multiple` - возможность множественного выбора, т. е., например, несколько братьев/сестер

`relations`

- `id`
- `type_id` - `id` в `relations_types`
- `user_id_from` - от кого выбор отношения
- `user_id_to` - какому пользователю
- `approved` - принял ли `user_id_to` отношение

Нужно вывести список доступных типов отношений из таблицы `relations` так, чтобы соблюдался пол пользователя (т. е. для женского пола не вывелся показатель "брат" и т.д.; для второй половинки нельзя было выбрать пользователя того же пола); так же записи с типом отношения не было в таблице `relations` (хотя это необязательное условие; приоритетнее первое).

Answer (score 2):

Если необходимо сделать выборку с проверкой пола, то тут относительно просто. Допустим у вас есть еще таблица `user` c полями `(id, title, sex)`, где `sex` - (0 - не указано, 1 - мужчина, 2 - женщина). Тогда можно выбрать все подходящие степени родства например так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `relation` R 
        JOIN `relations_types` T ON R.`type_id` = T.`id`
        JOIN `user` UF ON R.`user_id_from` = UF.`id`
        JOIN `user` UT ON R.`user_id_to` = UT.`id`
    WHERE T.`sex` = 0 
        OR T.`sex` = 1 AND UT.`sex` = 1 
        OR T.`sex` = 2 AND UT.`sex` = 2
        OR T.`sex` = 3 AND ( 
            UT.`sex` = 1 AND UF.`sex` = 2 
            OR  UT.`sex` = 2 AND UF.`sex` = 1
        )
```

Однако проблем тут будет еще предостаточно:

1. Нужно будет проверить родственников на количество (согласно полю `relations_types`.`is_multiple`) и на дублирование (когда одной и той же паре `user_id_from`, `user_id_to` был задан только один тип отношения);
2. Таке проверить на предмет коллизий (чтобы братья не оказались с разными родителями (хотя это наверное вопрос спорный);
3. У вас в логике построения таблицы `relations_types`, на мой взгляд, есть проблема. Могут быть типы отношений, которые не просто подразумевают разный пол у пары людей, а подразумевают строго конкретную пару (ММ, МЖ, ЖМ, ЖЖ). Поэтому ограничений по полу надо еще добавить (ну и проверок в запрос добавить).